# Colocar um array em uma Session

Tags: php, array, session

Ola, eu tenho um array com uma grande quantidade de valores que preciso passar para uma `session`,
eu estou tentando desta forma:

```php
array_push($array_tabela ,$tabela);
$_SESSION['tabela'] =  $array_tabela;
```

Porem o problema é quando eu pego a `session` em outra pagina esta com somente um elemento no array
[image: array com apenas um elemento]

Comment: Consegue montar um [mcve] demonstrando o problema?

Comment: Claro vou montar

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo você a utilizar **$_SESSION['tabela']=json_enconde($array_tabela)** para armazenar e quando foi utilizar a array novamente usa o **$_SESSION['tabela']=json_decode($array_tabela,true)**